# falcon gunicorn ImportError: No module named hparams

Tags: gunicorn, importerror, falconframework

I have already been working on a source that I have already created using gunicorn and nginx so that multiple people can access it without any problems.

Previously, falcon was running as a .py, but https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-falcon-web-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04 
There was a problem while referring to site

my program's name is `demo_server.py` 
and that code includes

```
import argparse
import falcon
from hparams import hparams, hparams_debug_string
import os
from synthesizer import Synthesizer // model (train model)
```

and when I type like these

```
gunicorn -b localhost: 5000 demo: app --reload
```

, The following error appears.

> Failed to read config file: demo_server.py Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "/data/falcon_app/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py",
>   line 93, in get_config_from_filename
>       execfile_ (filename, cfg, cfg)   File "/data/falcon_app/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/*compat.py",
>   line 72, in execfile*
>       return six.exec_ (code, * args)   File "demo_server.py", line 3, in 
>       from hparams import hparams, hparams_debug_string ImportError: No module named 'hparams'

How do I resolve this ImportError?
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have installed gunicorn which corresponds to **python2.7** on your local machine and you had to use **python3.x** which contains site-packages to run your falcon application.
Try install gunicorn3

```
sudo apt install gunicorn3
```

and then

```
gunicorn3 demo_server:app
```

worked for me